# How to linearize time-variant ordinary differential equation (ODE), in particular, if there is a convolution term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, distribution-theory, convolution, linearization

Letting $(\ * \ )$ denote convolution,  I have an ODE of the form
\begin{align}
\dot{r} &= -7.4r  -1.6f - 8.8 (f(t)*e^{-t}) - 10.4(f(t)*(te^{-t}))  \\
\dot{f} &= 0.25r
\end{align}
with initial conditions $r(0) = f(0) = 0.$

I would like to linearize about $[r=0, f=0]^t$. I realized that in general I can linearize when I have a time invariant ODE;  e.g., letting $x(t) = [r,f]^t$ I can linearize $\dot{x} = g(x)$.

I realized I do not know how to linearize a general equation of the form $\dot{x} = g(x,t)$ (time varying). How do we linearize time-variant ODEs?

Aside from the general question, there is a more specific question--how do we linearize the convolution terms? It seems I need to compute
$\frac{\partial }{\partial f}$ of the operator $f\mapsto (f(t)*e^{-t})$. This implies we are considering the derivative of an operator defined on a function space---what are the function spaces and norms/topologies in play here?

Comment: The convolution terms are linear in $f$: $$(cf*g)(t)=c(f*g)(t).$$

Comment: Yes, i conflated the notion of linear and time invariant. I agree it is linear. I had in my mind that the linearization process provides a time invariant and linear equation. I'm not sure how/why i got those two conflated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard-wired convolutions in the first rhs "hide" the actual linear, autonomous (rhs does not explicitely depend on $t$, which is actually mute in your notation $f(t)*e^{-t}$) 4th order equivalent system:
$$
\begin{align*}
r'&=-7.4r-1.6f-8.8q-10.4s\\
f'&=0.25r\\
q'&=-q+f\\
s'&=-s+q
\end{align*}
$$
with $q(0)=s(0)=0$. Hence as already said, no linearization is needed.

Comment: Thank you! I was conflating the notion of linearization and time invariant. So you're saying the original equation was linear (bc convolutions are) and time variant (b/c the convolutions values change in time)--i agree w/ this. You're saying that by making it a 4 order system we can eliminate the fact that it is time variant. Can we always eliminate time invariance with the extra equations? I thought that trick only eliminated orders (e.g., change a single 2nd order equation to a system of two 1st order equations).

Comment: The right term is autonomous (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)). Mathematically speaking, you can even replace a system of linear autonomous odes as yours by a single relationship using a matrix exponential, with no convolution at the end.

Comment: Can you tell me why you said this is "fourth order equivalent". I thought order meant difference between the highest and lowest derivative that appears.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you said "with $q(0) = s(0) = 0$". Perhaps you meant since $e^0 = 1$ and $0e^0 = 0$ ?

Comment: One denotes equivalently of fourth order a system of four first order differential equations or a single ode with  derivatives of at most fourth oder. $q(0)=0$ and $s(0)$ are the initial conditions of the last two differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

The set of odes is linear. You can solve it using the Laplace Transform.

\begin{align}
s\hat{r} &= -7.4\hat r  -1.6\hat f - 8.8 \hat f\frac{1}{s+1}- 10.4\hat f\frac{1}{(s+1)^2} + r_0 \\
s\hat {f} &= 0.25\hat r+ f_0
\end{align}

thus obtaining

$$
\cases{
\hat r = \frac{r_0 s (s+1)^2-f_0 ((1.6 s+12.) s+20.8)}{s^4+9.4 s^3+16.2 s^2+10.4 s+5.2}\\
\hat f=\frac{s^2 (f_0 (1. s+7.4)+0.25 r_0)}{s^4+9.4 s^3+16.2 s^2+10.4 s+5.2}
}
$$

NOTE

If $r_0 = f_0 = 0$ then the solution is the trivial solution: $\hat f = \hat r = 0$